# cordova 7.x add custom platform - which benefits do we get?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

yesterday I read the release-notes about [Cordova 7.0.0](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html). they presented the new feature of adding custom platforms with

```
cordova platform add custom-platform-name
```

I didn't found any references about this. Can anybody tell me, which new possibilties we have with this feature? 
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mentioned on a discuss thread [here](https://github.com/cordova/cordova-discuss/issues/64). As far as I can tell, the main change was restricting that a platform must be "known" by Cordova in order to install. Now any platform that conforms to the API can be installed.

I think the use cases for this are supporting platforms that Cordova does not support, or creating alternate versions of the standard platforms where a fork would not apply. I haven't found much documentation for the feature, but there's an empty shell of a platform [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-test-platform) to look at.